# Constant velocity vs. acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, friction, velocity

I am told that a block is slowing down due to friction. Is it moving at constant velocity or accelerating?

Answer (score 1):

From your question:

> I am told that a block is slowing down due to friction. Is it moving at constant velocity or accelerating?

Right from the get go, you are told that the block is "slowing down". Slowing down is synonymous with deceleration, which is defined as acceleration in the direction opposite the velocity. Thus, in answer to your question: **the block is accelerating**.

---

### In-Depth Description

*Example from your question:*

An object with a mass $m=1kg$ is moving with a velocity $v=5.0\frac{m}{s}[\text{right}]$ and is being acted on by a frictional force $F_A=1N[\text{left}]$.

**Consider Newton's First Law**

Newton's first law states that an object will remain at rest or moving with constant velocity is the forces $F_{net}$ acting on the object are balanced (sum to $0$).

As per this law, to determine whether an object is accelerating, what must be known is the net force $F_{net}$ acting on the object. To calculate $F_{net}$ find the sum of all the forces acting on the object:

$$F_{net}=\sum_n F_n$$

**Consider Newton's Second Law**

Newton's second law states that if the net force $F_{net}$ acting on an object is unbalanced, the object will accelerate with a magnitude directly proportional to, and in the same direction as, the unbalanced $F_{net}$:

$$F=ma \Rightarrow F_{net}=ma$$

If the object is being acted on by a frictional force $F_f$, and the force is not being balanced by some other force $F_A$, it will produce an acceleration directly proportional to $F_f$.

Solving for the acceleration $a$ from the example, $a=\frac{F_f}{m}=\frac{1N[\text{left}]}{1kg}=1\frac{m}{s^2}[\text{left}]$

You will notice that the acceleration $a$ is opposite in direction to the velocity $v$ (this will always be the case if the acceleration is caused solely by friction). This means that, over time, the velocity will decrease.

**Terminology**

Now, when can you use the term "slowing down"? As I said in the initial answer, slowing down is synonymous with deceleration. In the case of an unbalanced force caused by a force of friction, the acceleration will always be 'deceleration', because it will always be opposite the direction of motion (objects are not sped up by friction).

To determine whether an object is decelerating, look at the directions of the acceleration and of the velocity. Provided that each of the terms have the same sign ($++$ or $--$), if the terms are opposite in direction then the object is decelerating, otherwise it is not. If the signs of the terms are opposite ($+-$ or $-+$) you can change the signs to be the same by reversing the direction of one of the terms ($-1\frac{m}{s}[\text{left}]$ is the same as $1\frac{m}{s}[\text{right}]$).

Answer (score 0):

The block would be accelerating (well, technically decelerating, but you get the idea). Why? It's slowing down, i.e., the velocity is changing, and acceleration is defined as change in velocity divided by time.

Let's think about this as a car, driving along at a constant velocity. When the velocity is constant, you don't feel like you're moving. You could look at the window and legitimately (well, depending on how you define legitimately) think the trees were moving backwards and you were standing still.

Now, imagine you have to slam on your breaks, because another car decided to pull in front of you. When that happens, you're thrown forward in your seat, right? That's because your inertia "wants" you to just keep moving forward, in accordance with Newton's first law, but a force is being applied to you, so Newton's first law no longer applies. Instead, you think about Newton's second law, $F=ma$, which clearly shows that an acceleration is occurring.

Similarly, a force (friction) is being applied to your block, so there is acceleration occurring.

Answer (score 0):

The term slowing down implies that the speed (magnitude of the velocity) of the block is decreasing and so if the direction of the velocity is taken to be positive then the acceleration is in the opposite direction.
Since the velocity is changing the body cannot be said to be travelling at constant velocity.

You have to be really careful and try and avoid using the word deceleration as a synonym for negative acceleration.
Consider a force which is in the opposite direction to the motion of a body.
That force will reduce the speed of the body and if the forces continues to act the body could stop and then increase its speed ie the direction of motion of the body has been reversed.
Using the term deceleration might be confusing in such a circumstance in that although the acceleration is always in the same direction you would have to sudden switch from calling it a deceleration whilst the speed was decreasing to acceleration, or negative deceleration!!,  when the speed was increasing in the opposite direction.

So best to always call a change in velocity an acceleration and if the speed is decreasing then the acceleration is in the opposite direction to the velocity and it would still be the same acceleration after the velocity of the body reversed direction. 
So after the body has reversed direction its velocity is in the negative direction as is the acceleration and as they are both in the same direction the speed of the body will be increasing.